# Swift and Firebase querying the database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a tableView of chats the user is a part of. I was following the firebase tutorials on their site and they said to easily get a list of chat rooms the user is a part of to create a child and add the names of the rooms to that child.

So my structure looks like this

```
Users
    UNIQUE KEY
        nickname: "name"
        rooms
            name: true
Room
etc etc
```

So in my cellForRow I used this code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    firebase.child("users").child(fUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]{
            self.names = (user.value?["participating"] as? String)!
        }
    })

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.names
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"

    return cell
}
```

I get a error and when I PO the names it comes up with an empty string

Can somebody help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it? Thank you

**EDIT 1**

I have gotten the code to partially work

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let ref = firebase.child("users").child(fUID).child("participating")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value)

        var dict = [String: Bool]()

        dict = snapshot.value as! Dictionary

        for (key, _) in dict {
            self.names = key
            print(self.names)
        }

        self.rooms.append(self.names)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.rooms.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.rooms[indexPath.row]

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"

    return cell
}
```

The issue now is that there is 2 items in the firebase...and it is only showing one of them

Comment: I would observe the entire array outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath.  For example in viewDidAppear. Then once you have the items from the fetch reload the tableview.

Comment: My issue is on the line self.names....i get an error EXC_BAD_Instruction....

Comment: The call to firebase you are making is in a callback - so the the whole way your setting it up is wrong. Move the firebase call to where I said above and not within that delegate method.

Comment: You're not understanding, I did that and still have the same issue

Comment: do a print(user) in the loop - comment out the part that is give you an error and see what you get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using is the challenge. Here's a simplified version:

```
let usersRef = firebase.child("users")
let thisUser = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(fUID)
let thisUsersRooms = thisUser.childByAppendingPath("rooms")

thisUsersRooms.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

     if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
          print("not found")
     } else {
          for child in snapshot.children {
               let roomName = child.key as String
               print(roomName) //prints each room name
               self.roomsArray.append(roomName)
          }

          self.myRoomsTableView.reloadData()
     }
})
```

That being said, this code should be called from within viewDidLoad to populate an array, and then as the tableView is refreshed the data should be pulled from that array to populate your cellView.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Great! Glad it helped!